# Use Javascript to list a specific directory in file path

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to determine which directory an article is in, and self-generate all the file paths in the page. I've got it working, except that I still need to manually input the year the page was created as a variable when the article is moved from a 'recent' directory into the archive. I'm hoping to fully automate the process by using javascript to return the value of a specific directory in the file path.

For example, if the file path is: news/foo/2015/bar/article.html I need to extract the text '2015' and place it in a variable named 'year'.

Note the directory names won't be consistent, so I don't think searching the string for 'foo' or 'bar' is an option, rather the script needs to return the text between the second-last and third-last forward slash, or just the last 4 characters before the second-last forward slash. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let p = "news/foo/2015/bar/article.htm";

let splitedPath = p.split('/');

// to get the right position of the year, may be the year position is dynamic;
let year = splitedPath.filter(ele => parseInt(ele)>0 && ele.length ==4);
console.log(year[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, worked perfectly. I just had to add 'if (year == "")' to my existing code to cover the instances where the article is recent and yet to be filed under a specific year. Much appreciated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem so bad, you can just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
let p = "news/foo/2015/bar/article.htm";

let year = p.split('/')[2];
```

You can also use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you want that as a proper number, if that matters.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, regex is another alternative if you really couldn't use split for some reason... but split definitely seems the better way to go.